# Intellij Pycharm skin for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, pycharm, skin, appearance

I really hate the colors of Visual Studio. I am coming from PyCharm, and I loved it there.

Is there a way to set a theme similar to PyCharm's dark theme in Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: yes you can use dark theme in vs19. open ssms.pkgundef file with any editor i.e. notepad++ with administrator from your IDE folder.  search for Remove Dark theme in that file and put comment to below line.  Now will see dark theme option under Tools> Environment > General > Color theme

Comment: also there are few plugins that you can download from visual studio marketplace for more customization of your IDE theme (search Color Themes for Visual Studio)

Comment: @MerHardik I don't want VS's dark theme. I want Pycharm's

Comment: @MerHardik Which plugin is the one I need?

Comment: in that case you can customize with theme editor like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ColorThemesforVisualStudio